# How check if marker is within viewport in Leaflet, given center and zoom level?

Tags: leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

Is it possible to check whether a point is within viewport using Leaflet?

I have `center` of viewport and `zoom` level. Is it possible to calculate boundaries having *only* those values?

Comment: The first question *"Is it possible to check whether a point is within viewport using Leaflet?"* is of general use to other SO readers. It is [answered by NTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55884690/199364). (The accepted answer is specific to situation where you only know center and zoom level.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have `center` of viewport and `zoom` level. Is it possible to calculate boundaries having those values?

No.

One needs the size of the map (e.g. in pixels) in order to calculate the visible bounds of the map viewport.

Think about the edge cases: a map 0 pixels high and 0 pixels wide will never contain a marker within its bounds, whereas a map of infinite size on an infinitely large screen will always contain any marker.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use [getBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-methods-for-getting-map-state) function of map and contains to check if marker is within viewport or not.

```
if(m.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()))
    //within viewport
```

Comment: Yes, I can. However, the question was about checking a point having only center and zoom level.

Comment: For related methods, see [Leaflet - Docs - Map - Methods for getting map state](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-methods-for-getting-map-state).